# Inline Animation style are not working in Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, jsx

I have implemented the timer using css with animation, its working as expected. Since the animation duration is dynamic i need to inject the css as inline styles.but when i convert it into JSX inline styles in react, animation is not working as it was working before.

```
<div className="wrapper">
    <div className="pie spinner" style={{
        animationDuration: `${sessionTimeout}s`,
        animationTimingFunction: "linear",
        animationDelay: `0s`,
        animationIterationCount: "infinite",
        animationDirection: "normal",
        animationFillMode: "none",
        animationPlayState: "running",
        animationName: "timer__rotate"
    }}></div>
    <div className="pie filler" style={{
        animationDuration: `${sessionTimeout}s`,
        animationTimingFunction: `steps(1)`,
        animationDelay: `0s`,
        animationIterationCount: "infinite",
        animationDirection: "reverse",
        animationFillMode: "none",
        animationPlayState: "running",
        animationName: "timer__opacity"}}></div>
    <div className="mask" style={{
        animationDuration: `${sessionTimeout}s`,
        animationTimingFunction: `steps(1)`,
        animationDelay: `0s`,
        animationIterationCount: "infinite",
        animationDirection: "normal",
        animationFillMode: "none",
        animationPlayState: "running",
        animationName: "timer__opacity"

    }}></div>
    <div className="timer">
        <div className="remaining_time">
            {sessionTimeout}
        </div>
        <div className="time">
            Seconds
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto;
    background: #fff;
  }
  .wrapper, .wrapper * {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
  }
  .timer{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 4;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .timer .remaining_time{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .timer .time{
     font-family: Roboto;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #000;
  }
  .wrapper .pie {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border: 5px solid rgba(2, 155, 237, 1);
  }

  .wrapper .spinner {
    border-radius: 100% 0 0 100% / 50% 0 0 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    border-right: none;
    /* animation: timer__rotate 60s linear infinite; */
  }

  .wrapper:hover .spinner,
  .wrapper:hover .filler,
  .wrapper:hover .mask {
    animation-play-state: running;
  }

  .wrapper .filler {
    border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0 / 0 50% 50% 0;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    /* animation: timer__opacity 60s steps(1, end) infinite reverse; */
    border-left: none;   
  }

  .wrapper .mask {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: inherit;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 3;
    /* animation: timer__opacity 60s steps(1, end) infinite; */

  }

  @keyframes timer__rotate {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  @keyframes timer__opacity {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    50%, 100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: did you inspect the element to see what is compiled?

Comment: Yeah, the css used in the jsx is the compiled version of the css used before

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code is that you are recalculating the animation duration on each state change. So on each state change the duration will be different. Set the animation duration only once, on component mount.

Try the below codesandbox code.

[image: Edit Prompt user before the session ends]

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to define animation style only in the css file only better than inline style because it's a messy code with reac also use shorthand animation property to make your code cleaner.